# Using a variable for a database file in embeded SQL in free RPG

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpg

I would like to write an sql statment, that works no matter what data file is wanted.
example:

exec sql select * from :variable;

I am getting a SQL0104 Error at the ":"
"Token not vaild. Valid Token :(NEW FINAL TABLE UNNEST LATERAL MLTABLE JSON_TABLE"

I tried to do it in different statemenst with "insert into :variable", but I get the same Error.
Is it maybe not possible and I have to hard code the databasefile into my code or is there a way around?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ***static SQL*** with a variable table name.

You'd need to use ***dynamic SQL*** via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`

```
wMySql = 'insert into ' + wTableName + ' values (1,''ABC'')';

exec SQL
  execute immediate :wMySql;
```

Note that `SELECT * FROM TABLE` is not a statement that can be dynamically run.  For that matter, a static version doesn't make sense.  `SELECT ... INTO :myData FROM MYTABLE` is a valid static statement, but can't be used dynamically.  Instead you'd need to use `VALUES (SELECT * from MYTABLE) into :myData` which can be run dynamically.

Here's an IBM example using [dynamic SQL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=cssiira-example-dynamic-sql-in-ile-rpg-application-that-uses-sql).
Note normally you'd see the `FETCH` in a loop to return multiple rows, as written this will just return the first row then end.  This also show the use of replacement variables `?` in the statement.  Which is a best practice as it prevents SQL injection attacks.  However note that you can't use a replacement variable for the table name or column names.

```
//**************************************************
//* Declare program variables.                     *
//* STMT initialized to the                        *
//* listed SQL statement.                          *
//**************************************************
DCL-S EMPNUM CHAR(6);
DCL-S NAME CHAR(15);
DCL-S STMT CHAR(500)
  INZ('SELECT LASTNAME FROM CORPDATA.EMPLOYEE +
       WHERE EMPNO = ?');
...
//*************************************************************
//* Prepare STMT as initialized in declare section            *
//*************************************************************
EXEC SQL PREPARE S1 FROM :STMT;

//*************************************
//* Declare Cursor for STMT           *
//*************************************
EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;

//*****************************************************
//* Assign employee number to use in select statement *
//*****************************************************
EMPNUM = '000110';

//**********************
//* Open Cursor        *
//**********************
EXEC SQL OPEN C1 USING :EMPNUM;

//***********************************************
//* Fetch record and put value of               *
//* LASTNAME into NAME                          *
//***********************************************
EXEC SQL FETCH C1 INTO :NAME;

//********************************
//* Program processes NAME here  *
//********************************
...
//******************
//* Close cursor   *
//******************
EXEC SQL CLOSE C1;
```